# MissingPropertyException: No such property: filename for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins + pipeline plugin + envInject plugin. I am trying to get values from property file in pipeline script. But it doesn't see variables. This is me property file:

```
filename = "1.txt"
```

This is how I set up property injection:
[image]

This is my script:

```
echo "${filename}"
```

Please, help me to get these values

Comment: You shouldn't need to wrap property values in `""`

Answer (score -1):

Where did you define variable "filename" ?

In order to access Jenkins project variables in EnvInject Plugin, you must first define it as **Project Parameters** (e.g. Check "This project is parameterized" and add a String Parameter "filename").
Only then you can call it within EnvInject script.